# While appending to file if condition always fails

Tags: java, string, file

Input:

```
 bank_details
 payee
 online_system_id
 transaction_id
 pass_num
 prev_tran_approved

 bank_details
 payee
 online_system_id
 transaction_id
 prev_tran_approved
```

Actual output of below code.

```
  bank_details
 payee
 online_system_id
 transaction_id
 pass_num
 prev_tran_approved
 online_system_id
 proc_online_system_id
 tran_reversed
 prev_tran_approved

 bank_details
 payee
 online_system_id
 transaction_id
 prev_tran_approved
 online_system_id
 proc_online_system_id
 tran_reversed
 prev_tran_approved
```

Expected Output:

```
 bank_details
 payee
 online_system_id
 transaction_id
 pass_num
 prev_tran_approved
 proc_online_system_id
 tran_reversed

 bank_details
 payee
 online_system_id
 transaction_id
 prev_tran_approved
 proc_online_system_id
 tran_reversed
```

The code given below is for reference.
The if conditions where I am checking for the existing string in the file is always returing true even if string is not present in the file .Kindly go through the code and suggest me the changes.

well the logic is we have to read a file which contains various rows where each record is separated bt a blank line.Depending upon the conditions which i have mentioned in the if block i.e if the string online_system_id is lready present in the file we will not append it and if it is not present then we will append it at the end of each block of record. This check is to be performed for 4 values i.e online_system_id,proc_online_system_id,tran_reversed,prev_tran_approved

```
   String line;
    File output = new File(outputDir, "post_tran.tbl");
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(output));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        if(line.trim().isEmpty()) { 
            if(!(line.contains("online_system_id"))){
                out.println("online_system_id");
            }
            if(!(line.contains("proc_online_system_id"))){
                out.println("proc_online_system_id");
            }    
            if(!(line.contains("tran_reversed"))){
                out.println("tran_reversed");
            }  
            if(!(line.contains("prev_tran_approved"))){
                out.println("prev_tran_approved");
            }  
        }
        out2.println(line);        //always print the current line
      }


      try{
        out2.close(); 
        br.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
      }
```

Comment: post the actual output, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

After explaining your logic, it looks like you need to keep track of which of the 4 special Strings appeared in the current record, and to add whichever of them didn't when the record ends. You can do it with 4 boolean variables.

```
boolean osi = false;
boolean posi = false;
boolean tr = false;
boolean pta = false;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    if(line.trim().isEmpty()) { 
        // end of record, print each of the 4 special Strings that didn't appear
        if(!osi){
            out.println("online_system_id");
        }
        if(!posi){
            out.println("proc_online_system_id");
        }    
        if(!tr){
            out.println("tran_reversed");
        }  
        if(!pta){
            out.println("prev_tran_approved");
        }
        osi = false;
        posi = false;
        tr = false;
        pta = false;  
    } else {
        // track appearance of the 4 special Strings
        if(line.contains("online_system_id")){
            osi = true;
        }
        if(line.contains("proc_online_system_id")){
            posi = true;
        }    
        if(line.contains("tran_reversed")){
            tr = true;
        }  
        if(line.contains("prev_tran_approved")){
            pta = true;
        }  
    }
    out.println(line);        //always print the current line
}
```

Comment: This is giving different answer.

Comment: @user3678383 what's the desired logic?

Comment: @user3678383 edited answer, based on your input and output sample.

Comment: @  Eran Well It is not necessary. Input can be in any order

Comment: @user3678383 In that case, you should explain the logic of producing the output instead of showing just one sample of input and output.

Comment: @user3678383 Edited answer to fit the logic you added to the question.

Comment: your code is running just for one record. It is not working with multiple records

Comment: @user3678383 It might not work for the last record if the last line of the file is not empty. If that's the case, you have to add special handling for the last record after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if(line.trim().isEmpty())
```

to

```
if(!line.trim().isEmpty())
```

also:

```
 if((line.contains("online_system_id"))){
                out.println("online_system_id");
            }
            if((line.contains("proc_online_system_id"))){
                out.println("proc_online_system_id");
            }    
            if((line.contains("tran_reversed"))){
                out.println("tran_reversed");
            }  
            if((line.contains("prev_tran_approved"))){
                out.println("prev_tran_approved");
            }
```

Comment: It gives totally different answer

Comment: Did you try this at your end?

Comment: you didnt get my question I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to get

Comment: Kindly go through input output files